# Get the variable values at runtime using reflection in Dlang

Tags: d, phobos

Is it possible to get the class/struct/other variables value during runtime in dlang to get/set its value? If yes how to do that please provide example.
And also is it possible to get the runtime variable value?

Ex:

```d
class S{ int svariable = 5;}
class B { int bvariable = 10;}
void printValue(T, T instanceVariable, string variableName) {
    writeln("Value of ",  variableName, "=", instanceVariable.variableName);
}
```

Output:

> Value of svariable = 5;
>      Value of bvariable = 10;

Comment: There has been some talk about [std.reflection](http://forum.dlang.org/post/rxrlggihbstxxriswwnp@forum.dlang.org) a bit ago.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through that thread but nothing available as library. While googling i just come across witchcraft same answer from @mitch_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a library named [witchcraft](https://github.com/Mihail-K/witchcraft) that allows for runtime reflection. There are examples of how to use it on that page.

Answer (score 4):

I'd first recommend trying a reflection library like @mitch_ mentioned. However, if you want to do without an external library, you can use [`getMember`](http://dlang.org/spec/traits.html#getMember) to get and set fields as well as invoke functions:

```
struct S {
    int i;
    int fun(int val) { return val * 2; }
}

unittest {
    S s;
    __traits(getMember, s, "i") = 5; // set a field
    assert(__traits(getMember, s, "i") == 5); // get a field
    assert(__traits(getMember, s, "fun")(12) == 24); // call a method
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is for compile-time reflection and you asked for runtime. So yeah, use witchcraft.